# How to reshape data from long to wide format

Tags: r, reshape, r-faq

I'm having trouble rearranging the following data frame:

```
set.seed(45)
dat1 <- data.frame(
    name = rep(c("firstName", "secondName"), each=4),
    numbers = rep(1:4, 2),
    value = rnorm(8)
    )

dat1
       name  numbers      value
1  firstName       1  0.3407997
2  firstName       2 -0.7033403
3  firstName       3 -0.3795377
4  firstName       4 -0.7460474
5 secondName       1 -0.8981073
6 secondName       2 -0.3347941
7 secondName       3 -0.5013782
8 secondName       4 -0.1745357
```

I want to reshape it so that each unique "name" variable is a rowname, with the "values" as observations along that row and the "numbers" as colnames. Sort of like this:

```
     name          1          2          3         4
1  firstName  0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
5 secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
```

I've looked at `melt` and `cast` and a few other things, but none seem to do the job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reshape three column data frame to matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix)

Comment: @Frank: this is a much better title. [tag:long-form] and [tag:wide-form] are the standard terms used. The other answer cannot be found by searching on those terms.

Comment: A much more canonical answer can be found at the question linked about, now with the name [Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/210673). In my opinion, it would have been better for this one to have been closed as a duplicate of that.

Comment: The fact that the other question has one answer with a lot of options doesn't make it necessarily better than this; which has also a lot of options but in several answers. Furthermore, the definition of a duplicate is *"This question already has answer here"* (with a link to another earlier asked question).

Comment: I check in every so often so see if Stack Overflow is still more annoying than helpful -- yup, it is. I'll stay gone.

Answer (score 366, accepted):

Using `reshape` function:

```
reshape(dat1, idvar = "name", timevar = "numbers", direction = "wide")
```

Comment: +1 and you don't need to rely on external packages, since `reshape` comes with `stats`. Not to mention that it's faster! =)

Comment: @indra_patil - I would likely use the reshape2 package as indicated in one of the other answers. You could create a new question that's specific to your use case and post it if you can't figure it out.

Comment: it seems it will create duplicated "name" columns, that may be wanted or not wanted by the author of this thread

Comment: `reshape` is an outstanding example for a horrible function API. It is very close to useless.

Comment: The `reshape` comments and similar argument names aren't all that helpful.  However, I have found that for long to wide, you need to provide `data =` your data.frame, `idvar` = the variable that identifies your groups, `v.names` = the variables that will become multiple columns in wide format, `timevar` = the variable containing the values that will be appended to `v.names` in wide format, `direction = wide`,  and `sep = "_"`.  Clear enough?  ;)

Comment: I would say base R still wins vote-wise by a factor of about 2 to 1

Comment: Sometimes there are two `idvars=`, in this case we can do the following: `reshape(dat1, idvar=c("name1", "name2"), timevar="numbers", direction="wide")`

Comment: How can one use *reshape* if there are 2 or more entries for each `idvar`? For instance, from the example data, I would have 2 values for `name=firstname` and `numbers=1`.

Answer (score 168):

The new (in 2014) `tidyr` package also does this simply, with `gather()`/`spread()` being the terms for `melt`/`cast`.

**Edit:** Now, in 2019, tidyr v 1.0 has launched and set `spread` and `gather` on a deprecation path, preferring instead `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer`, which you can find described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57013551/903061). Read on if you want a brief glimpse into the brief life of `spread/gather`.

```
library(tidyr)
spread(dat1, key = numbers, value = value)
```

From [github](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr),

> `tidyr` is a reframing of `reshape2` designed to accompany the tidy data framework, and to work hand-in-hand with `magrittr` and `dplyr` to build a solid pipeline for data analysis.
>
> Just as `reshape2` did less than reshape, `tidyr` does less than `reshape2`. It's designed specifically for tidying data, not the general reshaping that `reshape2` does, or the general aggregation that reshape did. In particular, built-in methods only work for data frames, and `tidyr` provides no margins or aggregation.

Comment: Just wanted to add a link to the [R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/) page that discusses the use of these functions from `tidyr` and `reshape2`. It provides good examples and explanations.

Answer (score 85):

You can do this with the `reshape()` function, or with the `melt()` / `cast()` functions in the reshape package. For the second option, example code is

```
library(reshape)
cast(dat1, name ~ numbers)
```

Or using `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dat1, name ~ numbers)
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that just using `cast` or `dcast` will not work nicely if you don't have a clear "value" column. Try `dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2),blah=c(8,4,7,6),index=c(1,2,1,2)); dcast(dat, id ~ index); cast(dat, id ~ index)` and you will not get what you expect. You need to explicitly note the `value/value.var` - `cast(dat, id ~ index, value="blah")` and `dcast(dat, id ~ index, value.var="blah")` for instance.

Comment: Note that reshape2 is deprecated and you should be migrating your code away from using it.

Comment: @dpel A more optimistic spin is to say that reshape2 is finally done and you can now use it without fear that Hadley will change it again and break your code!

Answer (score 64):

Another option if performance is a concern is to use `data.table`'s extension of `reshape2`'s melt & dcast functions

([Reference: Efficient reshaping using data.tables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html))

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat1)
dcast(dat1, name ~ numbers, value.var = "value")

#          name          1          2         3         4
# 1:  firstName  0.1836433 -0.8356286 1.5952808 0.3295078
# 2: secondName -0.8204684  0.4874291 0.7383247 0.5757814
```

And, as of data.table v1.9.6 we can cast on multiple columns

```
## add an extra column
dat1[, value2 := value * 2]

## cast multiple value columns
dcast(dat1, name ~ numbers, value.var = c("value", "value2"))

#          name    value_1    value_2   value_3   value_4   value2_1   value2_2 value2_3  value2_4
# 1:  firstName  0.1836433 -0.8356286 1.5952808 0.3295078  0.3672866 -1.6712572 3.190562 0.6590155
# 2: secondName -0.8204684  0.4874291 0.7383247 0.5757814 -1.6409368  0.9748581 1.476649 1.1515627
```

Comment: `data.table` approach is the best ! very efficient ... you will see the difference when `name` is a combination of 30-40 columns !!

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.  For multiple columns, I got "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact)", and could fix this by forcing the use of data.table dcast: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44271092/190791

Answer (score 61):

With tidyr, there is `pivot_wider()` and `pivot_longer()` which are generalized to do reshaping from long -> wide or wide -> long, respectively. Using the OP's data:

**single column long -> wide**

```
library(tidyr)

dat1 %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = numbers, values_from = value)

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   name          `1`    `2`    `3`    `4`
#   <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 firstName   0.341 -0.703 -0.380 -0.746
# 2 secondName -0.898 -0.335 -0.501 -0.175
```

**multiple columns long -> wide**

`pivot_wider()` is also capable of more complex pivot operations. For example, you can pivot multiple columns simultaneously:

```
# create another column for showing the functionality
dat2 <- dat1 %>% 
    dplyr::rename(valA = value) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(valB = valA * 2) 

dat2 %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = numbers, values_from = c(valA, valB))

# # A tibble: 2 × 9
#   name       valA_1 valA_2 valA_3 valA_4 valB_1 valB_2 valB_3 valB_4
#   <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 firstName   0.341 -0.703 -0.380 -0.746  0.682 -1.41  -0.759 -1.49 
#  2 secondName -0.898 -0.335 -0.501 -0.175 -1.80  -0.670 -1.00  -0.349
```

There is much more functionality to be found in the [docs](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html).

Answer (score 31):

Using your example dataframe, we could:

```
xtabs(value ~ name + numbers, data = dat1)
```

Comment: this one is good, but the result is of format table which not may be not so easy to handle as data.frame or data.table, both has plenty of packages

Comment: The result is just a matrix with a fancy class name. When `x` is the result of `xtabs`, `attr(x,"class")=NULL;class(x)` returns `[1] "matrix" "array"`. This makes it look like a regular matrix: `attr(x,"class")=NULL;attr(x,"call")=NULL;dimnames(x)=unname(dimnames(x))`.

Comment: This converts the result of `xtabs` to a dataframe: `class(x)=NULL;as.data.frame(x)`. Without `class(x)=NULL`, the result is converted back to long format.

Answer (score 28):

Other two options:

Base package:

```
df <- unstack(dat1, form = value ~ numbers)
rownames(df) <- unique(dat1$name)
df
```

`sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN numbers = 1 THEN value ELSE NULL END) x1, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN numbers = 2 THEN value ELSE NULL END) x2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN numbers = 3 THEN value ELSE NULL END) x3,
      MAX(CASE WHEN numbers = 4 THEN value ELSE NULL END) x4
      FROM dat1
      GROUP BY name')
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding numbers, the query can be set up like this: ```ValCol <- unique(dat1$numbers);s <- sprintf("MAX(CASE WHEN numbers = %s THEN value ELSE NULL END) `%s`,", ValCol, ValCol);mquerym <- gsub('.{1}$','',paste(s, collapse = "\n"));mquery <- paste("SELECT name,", mquerym, "FROM dat1", "GROUP BY name", sep = "\n");sqldf(mquery)```

Answer (score 20):

Using base R `aggregate` function:

```
aggregate(value ~ name, dat1, I)

# name           value.1  value.2  value.3  value.4
#1 firstName      0.4145  -0.4747   0.0659   -0.5024
#2 secondName    -0.8259   0.1669  -0.8962    0.1681
```

Answer (score 16):

The base `reshape` function works perfectly fine:

```
df <- data.frame(
  year   = c(rep(2000, 12), rep(2001, 12)),
  month  = rep(1:12, 2),
  values = rnorm(24)
)
df_wide <- reshape(df, idvar="year", timevar="month", v.names="values", direction="wide", sep="_")
df_wide
```

Where

- `idvar` is the column of classes that separates rows
- `timevar` is the column of classes to cast wide
- `v.names` is the column containing numeric values
- `direction` specifies wide or long format
- the optional `sep` argument is the separator used in between `timevar` class names and `v.names` in the output `data.frame`.

If no `idvar` exists, create one before using the `reshape()` function:

```
df$id   <- c(rep("year1", 12), rep("year2", 12))
df_wide <- reshape(df, idvar="id", timevar="month", v.names="values", direction="wide", sep="_")
df_wide
```

Just remember that `idvar` is required! The `timevar` and `v.names` part is easy. The output of this function is more predictable than some of the others, as everything is explicitly defined.

Answer (score 12):

There's very powerful new package from genius data scientists at Win-Vector (folks that made `vtreat`, `seplyr` and `replyr`) called `cdata`. It implements "coordinated data" principles described in [this document](https://github.com/WinVector/cdata/blob/master/extras/RowsAndColumns.md) and also in this [blog post](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2017/03/coordinatized-data-a-fluid-data-specification/). The idea is that regardless how you organize your data, it should be possible to identify individual data points using a system of "data coordinates". Here's a excerpt from the recent blog post by John Mount:

> The whole system is based on two primitives or operators
>   cdata::moveValuesToRowsD() and cdata::moveValuesToColumnsD(). These
>   operators have pivot, un-pivot, one-hot encode, transpose, moving
>   multiple rows and columns, and many other transforms as simple special
>   cases.
>
> It is easy to write many different operations in terms of the
>   cdata primitives. These operators can work-in memory or at big data
>   scale (with databases and Apache Spark; for big data use the
>   cdata::moveValuesToRowsN() and cdata::moveValuesToColumnsN()
>   variants). The transforms are controlled by a control table that
>   itself is a diagram of (or picture of) the transform.

We will first build the control table (see [blog post](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2017/03/coordinatized-data-a-fluid-data-specification/) for details) and then perform the move of data from rows to columns.

```
library(cdata)
# first build the control table
pivotControlTable <- buildPivotControlTableD(table = dat1, # reference to dataset
                        columnToTakeKeysFrom = 'numbers', # this will become column headers
                        columnToTakeValuesFrom = 'value', # this contains data
                        sep="_")                          # optional for making column names

# perform the move of data to columns
dat_wide <- moveValuesToColumnsD(tallTable =  dat1, # reference to dataset
                    keyColumns = c('name'),         # this(these) column(s) should stay untouched 
                    controlTable = pivotControlTable# control table above
                    ) 
dat_wide

#>         name  numbers_1  numbers_2  numbers_3  numbers_4
#> 1  firstName  0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
#> 2 secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
```

Comment: Answer needs updating, since the package seems to be rewritten (and links are dead)

Answer (score 7):

much easier way!

```
devtools::install_github("yikeshu0611/onetree") #install onetree package

library(onetree)
widedata=reshape_toWide(data = dat1,id = "name",j = "numbers",value.var.prefix = "value")
widedata

        name     value1     value2     value3     value4
   firstName  0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
  secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
```

if you want to go back from wide to long, only change Wide to Long, and no changes in objects.

```
reshape_toLong(data = widedata,id = "name",j = "numbers",value.var.prefix = "value")

        name numbers      value
   firstName       1  0.3407997
  secondName       1 -0.8981073
   firstName       2 -0.7033403
  secondName       2 -0.3347941
   firstName       3 -0.3795377
  secondName       3 -0.5013782
   firstName       4 -0.7460474
  secondName       4 -0.1745357
```

Answer (score 1):

This works even if you have missing pairs and it doesn't require sorting (`as.matrix(dat1)[,1:2]` can be replaced with `cbind(dat1[,1],dat1[,2])`):

```
> set.seed(45);dat1=data.frame(name=rep(c("firstName","secondName"),each=4),numbers=rep(1:4,2),value=rnorm(8))
> u1=unique(dat1[,1]);u2=unique(dat1[,2])
> m=matrix(nrow=length(u1),ncol=length(u2),dimnames=list(u1,u2))
> m[as.matrix(dat1)[,1:2]]=dat1[,3]
> m
                    1          2          3          4
firstName   0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
```

This doesn't work if you have missing pairs and it requires sorting, but it's a bit shorter in case the pairs are already sorted:

```
> u1=unique(dat1[,1]);u2=unique(dat1[,2])
> dat1=dat1[order(dat1[,1],dat1[,2]),] # not actually needed in this case
> matrix(dat1[,3],length(u1),,T,list(u1,u2))
                    1          2          3          4
firstName   0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
```

Here's a function version of the first approach (add `as.data.frame` to make it work with tibbles):

```
l2w=function(x,row=1,col=2,val=3,sort=F){
  u1=unique(x[,row])
  u2=unique(x[,col])
  if(sort){u1=sort(u1);u2=sort(u2)}
  out=matrix(nrow=length(u1),ncol=length(u2),dimnames=list(u1,u2))
  out[cbind(x[,row],x[,col])]=x[,val]
  out
}
```

Or if you only have the values of the lower triangle, you can do this:

```
> euro=as.matrix(eurodist)[1:3,1:3]
> lower=data.frame(V1=rownames(euro)[row(euro)[lower.tri(euro)]],V2=colnames(euro)[col(euro)[lower.tri(euro)]],V3=euro[lower.tri(euro)])
> lower
         V1        V2   V3
1 Barcelona    Athens 3313
2  Brussels    Athens 2963
3  Brussels Barcelona 1318
> n=unique(c(lower[,1],lower[,2]))
> full=rbind(lower,setNames(lower[,c(2,1,3)],names(lower)),data.frame(V1=n,V2=n,V3=0))
> full
         V1        V2   V3
1 Barcelona    Athens 3313
2  Brussels    Athens 2963
3  Brussels Barcelona 1318
4    Athens Barcelona 3313
5    Athens  Brussels 2963
6 Barcelona  Brussels 1318
7    Athens    Athens    0
8 Barcelona Barcelona    0
9  Brussels  Brussels    0
> l2w(full,sort=T)
          Athens Barcelona Brussels
Athens         0      3313     2963
Barcelona   3313         0     1318
Brussels    2963      1318        0
```

Or here's another approach:

```
> rc=as.matrix(lower[-3])
> n=sort(unique(c(rc)))
> m=matrix(0,length(n),length(n),,list(n,n))
> m[rc]=lower[,3]
> m[rc[,2:1]]=lower[,3]
> m
          Athens Barcelona Brussels
Athens         0      3313     2963
Barcelona   3313         0     1318
Brussels    2963      1318        0
```

Another simple method in base R is to use `xtabs`. The result of `xtabs` is basically just a matrix with a fancy class name, but you can make it look like a regular matrix with `class(x)=NULL;attr(x,"call")=NULL;dimnames(x)=unname(dimnames(x))`:

```
> x=xtabs(value~name+numbers,dat1);x
            numbers
name                  1          2          3          4
  firstName   0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
  secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
> str(x)
 'xtabs' num [1:2, 1:4] 0.341 -0.898 -0.703 -0.335 -0.38 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ name   : chr [1:2] "firstName" "secondName"
  ..$ numbers: chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
 - attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = value ~ name + numbers, data = dat1)
> class(x)
[1] "xtabs" "table"
> class(as.matrix(x)) # `as.matrix` has no effect because `x` is already a matrix
[1] "xtabs" "table"
> class(x)=NULL;class(x)
[1] "matrix" "array"
> attr(x,"call")=NULL;dimnames(x)=unname(dimnames(x))
> x # now it looks like a regular matrix
                    1          2          3          4
firstName   0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
> str(x)
 num [1:2, 1:4] 0.341 -0.898 -0.703 -0.335 -0.38 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "firstName" "secondName"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Normally `as.data.frame(x)` converts the result of `xtabs` back to long format, but you can avoid it with `class(x)=NULL`:

```
> x=xtabs(value~name+numbers,dat1);as.data.frame(x)
        name numbers       Freq
1  firstName       1  0.3407997
2 secondName       1 -0.8981073
3  firstName       2 -0.7033403
4 secondName       2 -0.3347941
5  firstName       3 -0.3795377
6 secondName       3 -0.5013782
7  firstName       4 -0.7460474
8 secondName       4 -0.1745357
> class(x)=NULL;as.data.frame(x)
                    1          2          3          4
firstName   0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
```

This converts data in wide fromat to long format (`unlist` converts a dataframe to a vector and `c` converts a matrix to a vector):

```
w2l=function(x)data.frame(V1=rownames(x)[row(x)],V2=colnames(x)[col(x)],V3=unname(c(unlist(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Came here via a linked question [Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix). That question is closed, so I writing an alternative solution here.

I found a alternative solution, perhaps useful for someone looking for converting three columns to a matrix. I am referring to decoupleR (2.3.2) package. Below is copied from their  [site](https://saezlab.github.io/decoupleR/reference/pivot_wider_profile.html)

---

Generates a kind of table where the rows come from id_cols, the columns from names_from and the values from values_from.

Usage

```
pivot_wider_profile(
data,
id_cols,
names_from,
values_from,
values_fill = NA,
to_matrix = FALSE,
to_sparse = FALSE,
...
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using only `dplyr` and `map`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
set.seed(45)
dat1 <- data.frame(
  name = rep(c("firstName", "secondName"), each=4),
  numbers = rep(1:4, 2), value = rnorm(8)
)
longer_to_wider <- function(data, name_from, value_from){
  group <- colnames(data)[!(colnames(data) %in% c(name_from,value_from))]
  data %>% group_by(.data[[group]]) %>%
    summarise( name = list(.data[[name_from]]), 
               value = list(.data[[value_from]])) %>%
    {
      d <- data.frame(
        name = .[[name_from]] %>% unlist() %>% unique()
      )
      e <- map_dfc(.[[group]],function(x){
          y <- data_frame(
            x = data %>% filter(.data[[group]] == x) %>% pull(value_from)
          )
          colnames(y) <- x
          y
      })
      cbind(d,e)
    }
}
longer_to_wider(dat1, "name", "value")
#    name          1          2          3          4
# 1  firstName  0.3407997 -0.7033403 -0.3795377 -0.7460474
# 2 secondName -0.8981073 -0.3347941 -0.5013782 -0.1745357
```